# After Effects audio spectrum error

Tags: adobe-after-effects

When I add Audio Spectrum, it plays well for the whole song but at end it stops working and only basic lines appear for 0 audio even if my song is not complete. I have tried this on both AE CC 2015 and AE CS6 but same problem.

How to play spectrum for the whole song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different settings for Audio Spectrum and found out that it was start and end frequencies for me, It worked like a charm.